# php preg_match_all construct pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying construct `preg_match_all` to search for all the values found in a string that begins with `[$_` and ends with `_$]`, and store the found values in an array.

So, in the following example:

```
$str = "I have a [$_dog_$], a [$_cat_$], but not a ferret.";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $str, $normalPets);
```

`$normalPets` should contain `[$_dog_$]` and `[$_cat_$]`.

What is the `$regex_pattern` for this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the good example and explanation. But. What have you tried?

Comment: preg_match_all("/^\[\$\_\_\$\]$/", $str, $normalPets);

Comment: Please note when  I posted this it removed the underscore before dog and after dog.  It should be [$_dog_$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
$regex_pattern = '/\[\$_.+_\$\]/U';
```

Comment: there is no need for the capturing group

Comment: also you should include the underscores

Comment: added the underscores and removed capturing group

Comment: Thanks. You are a regex genius, although it's storing [$_dog_$] and [$_cat_$]  twice.  I can deal with that with an array function but is there something in the regex pattern that is causing the found values to be stored 2x?

Comment: The reason for this is the way how the result is stored in $normalPets. The first entry is for the whole match and all the following entries (in you case only one) for all sub patterns. Unless you use the PREG_SET_ORDER constant as the fourth parameter $normalPets[0] should contain your result.